# How to troubleshoot COM port problem in Virtual PC 2007?

Tags: virtualization, microsoft-virtual-pc

Host: Windows XP SP3
Guest: Windows XP SP3
Virtual PC 2007 (6.0.156.0)

I have two serial devices attached to the host (chip and pin card readers).
These work with my application when running on the host.

On the guest OS, I have mapped virtual COM ports to the physical ones and these show up in Device Manager.

I am unable to download config data to the devices.
SysInternals PortMon on the guest allows me to see data being sent:

ddl.exe IRP_MJ_CREATE   Serial0 SUCCESS Options: Open   
ddl.exe IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_WAIT_MASK  Serial0 SUCCESS Mask:   
ddl.exe IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_BAUD_RATE  Serial0 SUCCESS     
ddl.exe IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_LINE_CONTROL   Serial0 SUCCESS 
ddl.exe IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_CHARS  Serial0 SUCCESS     
ddl.exe IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_HANDFLOW   Serial0 SUCCESS     
ddl.exe IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_BAUD_RATE  Serial0 SUCCESS     
ddl.exe IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_LINE_CONTROL   Serial0 SUCCESS 
ddl.exe IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_CHARS  Serial0 SUCCESS     
ddl.exe IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_HANDFLOW   Serial0 SUCCESS     
ddl.exe IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_BAUD_RATE  Serial0 SUCCESS Rate: 57600
ddl.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_RTS    Serial0 SUCCESS     
ddl.exe IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_DTR    Serial0 SUCCESS     
ddl.exe IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_LINE_CONTROL   Serial0 SUCCESS StopBits: 1 Parity: NONE WordLength: 8  
ddl.exe IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_CHAR   Serial0 SUCCESS EOF:0 ERR:0 BRK:0 EVT:0 XON:11 XOFF:13  
ddl.exe IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_HANDFLOW   Serial0 SUCCESS Shake:1 Replace:40 XonLimit:2048 XoffLimit:512  
ddl.exe IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_TIMEOUTS   Serial0 SUCCESS RI:0 RM:0 RC:0 WM:0 WC:0    
ddl.exe IRP_MJ_WRITE    Serial0 SUCCESS Length 1: . 
ddl.exe IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_TIMEOUTS   Serial0 SUCCESS RI:-1 RM:0 RC:0 WM:0 WC:0   
ddl.exe IRP_MJ_READ Serial0 SUCCESS Length 0:   
ddl.exe IRP_MJ_WRITE    Serial0 SUCCESS Length 1: . 
ddl.exe IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_TIMEOUTS   Serial0 SUCCESS RI:-1 RM:0 RC:0 WM:0 WC:0   
ddl.exe IRP_MJ_READ Serial0 SUCCESS Length 0:

The devices just sit perpetually waiting for data.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the devices were hard-coded to communicate at 115,200 baud and do not negotiate speed. Once I changed from 57,600 baud, all was well.